# C in Xcode having trouble with creating file

Tags: c, xcode, macos

I am new to Xcode and I an currently learning C. How does file opening work here?

When I was using Windows and I declared that I want to write to file e.g.:

```
FILE *fr;
fr = fopen("test.txt","w");
```

it created file if it did not exist.
But here in Mac I don't see file anywhere.

Any help about where will file be created on mac would be really appreciated.

Comment: "*i don't see file anywhere*" are you sure you are looking at the right place? Consider specifying an absolute path, for debugging at least.

Comment: If `fopen` isn't working it would return `NULL` You should probably check that.

Comment: i open finder and to search bar i write test.txt and it just find nothing.. you mean something like /diskname/desktop/test.txt?

Comment: Yah yonlif, but also when you want to create file you make it "w" for write and then it should create itself. I heard that it will write NULL when file does not exist.. but declaring that i want file to be for write should create new file

Comment: I'm aware that you are trying to create and write to a new file, but instead of searching for it you should check if it was created by this `NULL` check.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370892/fopen-not-working-in-c).

Comment: I readed that and what i found out is that file exist. But i couldn't find where..

Comment: I used perror for that tho

Comment: I also tryed NULL but suprisingly this one was not working...        code was: FILE *fr = fopen("test.txt","r"); (r because w was not longer necessary since file was created as perror wrote.) then if (fr=='NULL') {printf ("File doesn't exist} else {printf("File exist!") }

Comment: Is there any code that will say me file location? You know like when i used ascii it told me that "A" is 65 etc..

Comment: You can try find it via terminal, or for some reason it's saved as an hidden file, or try to save it in `\.` directory and see if it works... I truly have no idea right now why you can't find it in this directory.

Comment: Thanks for your kind advices, I will go ahead and try it. Will tell you what was problem if I will find out. Thanks

Comment: The file, given the `fopen()` statement, will be in the same directory as where the executable is executed.  To properly check for errors when calling `fopen()` use: `FILE *fr;
fr = fopen("test.txt","w");  if( !fr ) { perror( "fopen failed" );`  Note: error messages are to be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  The `perror()` will output the enclosed text AND the reason the system thinks the function failed.